# What does ASDL stand for?

Tags: python, terminology, acronym, asdl

I see in the [`ast` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

```
-- ASDL's 7 builtin types are:
-- identifier, int, string, bytes, object, singleton, constant
```

In that context what does ASDL stand for? Is it just the cpython grammar?

Comment: http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Abstract-Type+and+Scheme-Definition+Language

Comment: @Prune not that one. =)

Comment: Abstract Syntax Description Lanuguage (ASDL) is a language designed to describe the tree-like data structures in compilers.

Comment: @EvanCarroll; sorry; I knew the abbreviation and grabbed a link with a merely *similar* name.

Comment: You're right, wikipedia doesn't have this option for disambiguation :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract Syntax Description Lanuguage (ASDL) is a language designed to describe the tree-like data structures in compilers

> The abstract syntax tree (AST) is a high-level representation of the program structure without the necessity of containing the source code; it can be thought of as an abstract representation of the source code. The specification of the AST nodes is specified using the [Zephyr Abstract Syntax Definition Language (ASDL)](http://asdl.sourceforge.net/) [Wang97](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0339/#wang97). [PEP 339 -- Design of the CPython Compiler](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0339/#id13)

You can see a [good write up of it here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/06/04/using-asdl-to-describe-asts-in-compilers)